# Inverse the input Expression using stacks

Tags: string, algorithm, stack, expression, reverse

I had a coding challenge as one of the process for recruitment into a company. In that coding challenge, one of the question was to inverse an expression.
For Example,
Input : 14-3*2/5
Output : 5/2*3-14

I used stack to put each number say 14 or 3 and expressions and then popped it out again to form the output.

Input format is : num op num op num op num
So we need not worry about input being -2.
num can be between -10^16 to 10^16. I was dealing with strings completely, so even if the number exceeds the 10^16 limit, my algorithm wouldn't have any problem.

My algorithm passed 7 test cases and failed in 2 of them.
I couldn't figure it out what the corner case would be. I couldn't see the test cases as well. Any idea what that might be.  I know there isn't enough information, but unfortunately I too don't have them.

```
// Complete the reverse function below.
static String reverse(String expression) {
    expression = expression.trim();
    if(expression == ""){
            return "";
        }
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        String num = "";
        for(int i=0; i<expression.length(); i++){
            char c = expression.charAt(i);
            if(c==' '){
                continue;
            }
            if(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/'){
                if(num != "") {
                    stack.push(num);
                }
                num = "";
                stack.push(Character.toString(c));
            } else{
                num += c;
            }
        }
        if(num != "") {
            stack.push(num);
        }

        String revExp = "";
        while(! stack.empty()){
            revExp = revExp + stack.pop();
        }

        return revExp;

}
```

Comment: Can't really help you if you don't show code...

Comment: Sorry abt that. Added the code

Comment: You don't seem to be taking operator precedence into account.

Comment: "num can be between -10^16 to 10^16": it seems that you do _need to worry_ about numbers like `-2`. Negative numbers are allowed.

Comment: You consider only +, -, * and /. Was this a requirement? What about, say, exponentiation, factorials?